# How to display posts based on sub categories of custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called "categories" and it's slug is "category". I have various categories like:

- Beauty

  - Makeup
  - Skincare
- Tech

I have these categories in a CPT called "Products". I want to display only those posts that match with a subcategory. For example, I want to display only those posts from CPT "Products" that have "Makeup" checked in categories custom taxonomy. I have tried the following code:

```
$args= new WP_Query( array(
         'post_type' => 'Products',
         'tax_query' => array(
                        array (
                                'taxonomy' => 'categories',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => 'Beauty',
                            )
                        ),
           ) );
     if($args->have_posts()):
        while ($args->have_posts()):$args->the_post();
           echo get_field('name');
        endwhile; 
     endif;
```

But this code obviously displays posts that have category checked as "Beauty". It doesn't check for subcategory. Can anyone help me out with this? Any modification to the current code would be helpful as well.
Thanks!

Comment: is this woocommerce products ?

Comment: No. Products is just custom post type. The data fed into this cpt comes from a form on the front end.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display posts from a certain subcategory you can simply use get_posts(), something like:

```
 $posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'Products',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'cat'      => your subcat ID,
    'posts_per_page'   => -1
));
```

And then loop through your posts like:

```
 foreach ($posts as $post){
     echo $post->post_title . '<br>';

 }
```

Comment: no need to over-complicate this, as far I understood you want posts from 1 certain subcategory, if this is not the case then tell me I'll edit the answer

Comment: You understood correctly. However, this displays all posts regardless of subcategory. How do I get the id of sub category?

Comment: Is there any way to do it dynamically so that it can be done even if client adds new subcategory?

Comment: Anything can be done yes, but you need to tell me what's exactly your user case scenario. What is it that you're trying to achieve and why archive.php template is not doing the job ? I mean when a user clicks on some of your subcats link anyways he sees posts only from this category displayed in the archive templayed.

Comment: Or you need a page to display products from all subcategories ?

Comment: Or you need a different template ( different from archive.php ) just for subcategories ?

Comment: Yes I'm using a different template. I have different pages for all categories. These pages have further options to select subcategories in each one of them. These options are buttons and images displayed using ACF. I could be doing this the wrong way. But when a subcategory image is clicked, it should redirect to another page that displays only those posts that matches with the subcategory. I hope this makes sense.